# What does cout << std::ios::hex do?

Tags: c++, std

This question comes from a bug that I got into recently. I was trying to save some integer values to file as hex. As an example, this is what I should do:

```
cout << std::hex << value << endl;                 // (1)
```

But by mistake, I use it as the following:

```
cout << std::ios::hex << value << endl;            // (2)
```

The compiler does not complain but obviously the result is not correct. I was trying a couple more values randomly and it seems that (2) actually give partially correct result except that it append **800** as a prefix. I don't understand where the **800** is coming from and I don't see a good reference anywhere. Can anybody explain what's happening under the hood?

```
cout << std::hex << 255 << endl;       // output: FF
cout << std::ios::hex << 255 << endl;  // output: 800ff

cout << std::hex << 135 << endl;       // output: 87
cout << std::ios::hex << 135 << endl;  // output: 80087

cout << std::hex << 11 << endl;        // output: b
cout << std::ios::hex << 11 << endl;   // output: 800b
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is actually `std::ios_base::hex`. It's an implementation-defined bitmask. Internally, the stream has an integer called [`fmtflags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) where it stores the current state of the formatting.

In your implementation, `hex` is the flag `0x800`.  Other flags will indicate whether it's in scientific notation mode, whether `boolalpha` is on, etc. etc.

The `std::hex` function sets the `std::ios_base::hex` flag in `fmtflags`.

So your output is the integer value of this flag (in hex since you sent `std::hex` previously).

Answer (score 11):

`std::hex` is a *manipulator*, i.e., it is a function with a specific signature:

```
std::ios_base& hex(std::ios_base& stream) {
    stream.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
    return stream;
}
```

There are some special output operators defined for stream to process manipulators. For the version operating on references to `std::ios_base` there is (ignoring that the operator is actually a function template):

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, std::ios_base&(*manip)(std::ios_base&));
```

When used with a stream, the manipulator function is being called and it sets a specific format flag, in this case `std::ios_base::hex` (which is how `std::ios::hex` is actually defined). Since `std::ios_base::hex` is a member of a group of flags (the others are `std::ios_base::dec` and `std::ios_base::oct`) setting it also needs to clear any potential other flag in the group. Thus, `setf()` is called with a mask (`std::ios_base::basefield`) to clear any of the other potentially set flags.

The format flags `std::ios_base::fmtflags` is a bitmask type. The value `std::ios_base::hex` is one of the values. When formatting it you'll get some number, most likely a power of 2 (however, it doesn't have to be a power of 2). The value you see is simply `0x800` (i.e. 2048) printed using hex notation: setting any of the formatting flags (other than the `width()`) is *sticky*, i.e., they remain until the flag is unset. If you want to see the value 2048 (for the implementation you are using) you'd use

```
std::cout << std::dec << std::ios_base::hex << "\n";      // 2048
std::cout << std::hex << std::ios_base::hex << "\n";      // 800
std::cout << std::showbase << std::ios_base::hex << "\n"; // 0x800
```

The last line sets the flag `showbase` which indicates the base of an integer value with a prefix:

- no prefix => decimal
- a leading `0x` => hexadecimal
- a leading `0` (but no `x`) => octal

Answer (score 6):

`std::hex` is a special object that, when applied to a stream using `operator<<`,

> sets the basefield of the stream `str` to hex as if by calling `str.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::base field)`

`std::ios::hex` (aka `std::ios_base::hex`) is the actual bitmask value that gets passed to the `setf` method. Its value is implementation defined, and it seems to be `0x800` in your case.